# How to copy multiple values between objects

Tags: modeling, interface, edit-mode

Lets say I have 2 objects and I want to copy the x, y, z coordinates, and scale along the y and z from one object to another. The way I would usually do this would be to copy each of the attributes separately while selecting first one object and then the other. I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this, using only one step. If not in one step, is there a way to do it in multiple, without having to repetitively select the objects and copy values by hand? I assume I could use a python script, but writing one every single time I wanted to do this operation seems doesn't seem very efficient.

I am using blender 2.8, but I can probably use an answer for 2.79. Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see at least 2 methods, perhaps there are other ones? Let say you want to copy scale, you can:

- Enable the *Copy Attributes* addon, select all the objects, select the one you want to copy the attribues at the end, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> > *Copy Scale*. But it will copy the whole scale, not the scale for one particular axis.
- You can keep in memory the scale you want to apply, select all your objects, then in the scale field of the 3D view properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>), type the value and press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>. With this second method you can choose the precise axis... but you need to type it (or copy paste it).

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the **Copy Attributes Menu** addon is enabled (by default embedded with Blender but not enabled). Then select first the object(s) that should receive the properties, then the target object holding the **Shift key > Ctrl-C > Copy Location/Rotation...**

[image: copymenu]